# Spring + LDAP Authentication + Google Sign in

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, ldap, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement **LDAP Authentication** and **Google Login** but I couldn't figure out how to send info about my user from frontend to backend.

I'm using React.JS on frontend and when I sign-in using the **react-google-login** package from npm, I get some info from Google(e.g. email, full name, etc.). And when I sign in with LDAP, I don't get anything(There is a JSESSIONID cookie shown in the chrome but there is no cookie in the response data from Spring.) I can successfully login in both but how can I know which person is sending request from frontend to backend?

Without using React, If I send a request to spring from Chrome or Postman(if I add the JSESSIONID cookie to Postman), I can authenticate the user with **SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()** if the user logins with LDAP, and from **OAuth2USer** object if the user logins with Google Sign in. But the problem is how can I send the same arguments from React?

I was searching to get a JWT from Spring as a response so that I can only send the JWT token to the backend to authorize but I couldn't figure out how to send it in both LDAP authentication and Google authentication and don't know if that would be an overkill.

My code in Spring so far:

**Web Security Config class**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userDetailsServiceImpl = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl();
    }

    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/user/authenticate", "/login", "/user/me").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user/add").hasRole(ADMIN.name())
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider())
                .ldapAuthentication()
                    .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .contextSource()
                        .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                        .and()
                    .passwordCompare()
                        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }
}
```

**Method to find the user in the controller**

```
   public User findUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User user) {
        Optional<User> foundUser;
        if (user == null) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            foundUser = userRepository.findUserByUserID(((UserDetailsImpl) auth.getPrincipal()).getUserID());
        }
        else {
            foundUser = userRepository.findUserByEmail(user.getAttributes().get("email").toString());
        }

        return foundUser.get();
    }
```